# Python: How to run ALL elif criterions?

Tags: python

I thought this could be a very beginners question. But I just dont know how to solve it. (Please dont give me minus, I tried to search, but didnot found.)

My codes:

```
num = 5     
if num == 3:
    print 'boss'        
elif num == 2:
    print 'user2'
elif num == 5:
    print 'user5'
elif num == 1:
    print 'worker'
elif num > 0:  #I also want to print this one. Because num is bigger than 0
    print 'error'
else:
    print 'roadman'
```

The desired results are:

```
user5
error
```

But it only shows me the result:

```
user5
```

My question: How to make sure **ALL** the `elif` criterions are considered?

Comment: make them just `if`s

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! But is there better idea than many `if`s

Comment: Based on the title of your question, the answer would be to change the `elif` statements to `if`. But a better solution would be to use a key-value mapping. I will post an answer soon

Comment: @doglas how is that harder than many `elifs`? You are typing 3 characters less every time...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga see my answer. I respond to OP's comment asking whether there is a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question asks how to evaluate all of the `elif` statements. The answer to that, as described by @juanpa.arrivillaga and @m_callens, is to convert them to `if` statements.

In the comments, you ask if there is a better way, and I think the better way is to use a key-value mapping. Based on your question, this mapping could be a dictionary:

```
mapping = {1: 'worker',
           2: 'user2',
           3: 'boss',
           5: 'user5'}
```

Then we can replace most of the `if` statements with a single dictionary query:

```
num = 5
print mapping[num]
```

However, a `KeyError` will be raised if the key does not exist in the dictionary. We can get around this with a `try-except` block. The `try` part will *try* to execute whatever is in that block. If it encounters a `KeyError` (i.e., the key does not exist in the dictionary), it will execute whatever is in the `except` block. This also takes care of the case where you want to display "roadman".

```
try:
    print(mapping[num])
except KeyError:
    print("roadman")
```

In the case you want to display "error" if `num > 0`, I would use an `if` statement. Putting all of this together, you have

```
mapping = {1: 'worker',
           2: 'user2',
           3: 'boss',
           5: 'user5'}

num = 5

if num > 0:
    print("error")

try:
    print(mapping[num])
except KeyError:
    print("roadman")
```

The output is:

```
error
user5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really like this way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

An `if-elif-else` structure like this is mutually exclusive and doesn't allow for fall-throughs in the conditions, so instead, just make the `'error'` statement have its own `if`

```
num = 5     
if num == 3:
    print 'boss'        
elif num == 2:
    print 'user2'
elif num == 5:
    print 'user5'
elif num == 1:
    print 'worker'
else:
    print 'roadman'

if num > 0:
    print 'error'
```

Comment: @CristiFati - I don't see how this is a work around - it's the correct usage of an if statement. Please add an answer what you think your non-workaround solution is, I'm very curious...

Comment: The outcome will be the same because they are mutually exclusive, but the question did technically ask how to consider **ALL** of the conditions. So all of the `elif`s should really be `if`s. Maybe the questioner is more interested in control flow in general, rather than making this specific example work. So I think that should be made clear.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out, I misread/misunderstood the question. Will delete my prev comment in minutes...